# What is the idiomatic Go way of testing for, and processing, multiple keys in a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a `map[string]string` and I need to test if some keys exist and if they do, convert some of the values to integers. For example:

```
m := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}
if v1, ok := m["a"]; ok {
  if v2, ok := m["c"]; ok {
     if i1, err := strconv.Atoi(v1); err != nil {
       if i2, err := strconv.Atoi(v2); err != nil {
         // do something with i1, i2
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I find myself thinking in the lines of:

```
if m.exists("a") && m.exists("c") && is_int(m["a"]) && is_int(m["c"]) {
   // do something with atoi(m["a"]) and atoi(m["c"])
}
```

... but that's not convenient with Go's standard library. So, what is the Go way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to create your own `map[string]string` type and add some simple methods to that. Here is a simple example:

```
type mapExists map[string]string

func (m mapExists) exists(key string) bool {
    _, ok := m[key]
    return ok
}

func (m mapExists) isInt(key string) bool {
    v, ok := m[key]
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    _, err := strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, 64)
    return err == nil
}
```

You can convert a `map[string]string` to the `mapExists` with:

```
m := map[string]string{
    "a": "b",
    "c": "2",
}

m2 := mapExists(m)
```

And then call stuff like in your example:

```
fmt.Println("a exists:\t", m2.exists("a"))
fmt.Println("asd exists:\t", m2.exists("asd"))
fmt.Println("a isInt:\t", m2.isInt("a"))
fmt.Println("c isInt:\t", m2.isInt("c"))
```

Which will output:

```
a exists:        true
asd exists:      false
a isInt:         false
c isInt:         true
```

---

Whether this is the "best" or "idiomatic" way is a matter of opinion and depends on the circumstances. In general, I would (personally) prefer to *not* use these wrappers. Your above example could be rewritten to something like the following :

```
func test() {
    m := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}

    v1, v1ok := m["a"]
    v2, v2ok := m["c"]
    if !v1ok || !v2ok {
       return
    }

    i1, err := strconv.Atoi(v1)
    if err != nil {
       return
    }
    i2, err := strconv.Atoi(v2) {
    if err != nil {
       return
    }
}
```

Which I think is much more readable. It's more verbose, but Go is a verbose language ;-)

But again, it depends on the entirety of your codebase. If you're calling this pattern very often then a custom type *might* be a good solution (at the cost of slightly lower performance, which may or may not be a problem).

Answer (score 3):

Testing if a `string` value is a number and converting it to a number is basically the same amount of work.

So I would rather use the following util function which besides checking the keys and testing the values also returns the converted numbers:

```
func getInts(m map[string]string, keys ...string) (is []int, err error) {
    for _, k := range keys {
        v, ok := m[k]
        if !ok {
            return is, fmt.Errorf("%s is missing", k)
        }
        var i int
        if i, err = strconv.Atoi(v); err != nil {
            return
        }
        is = append(is, i)
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it with 3 different cases:

```
maps := []map[string]string{
    {},
    {"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"},
    {"a": "1", "c": "2", "e": "f"},
}

for _, m := range maps {
    if is, err := getInts(m, "a", "c"); err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Numbers:", is)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WztZIraxFG)):

```
Error: a is missing
Error: strconv.Atoi: parsing "b": invalid syntax
Numbers: [1 2]
```